# UWP Vpn AddProfileFromObjectAsync always return "other" error

Tags: c#, uwp, vpn, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to create a new VPN profile in a universal windows app. I am using [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.vpn?view=winrt-22621).

```
public async void connect()
        {
            var connectionProfile = new VpnNativeProfile
            {
                AlwaysOn = true,
                NativeProtocolType = VpnNativeProtocolType.IpsecIkev2,
                ProfileName = "TestProfile",
                RememberCredentials = true,
                RequireVpnClientAppUI = true,
                RoutingPolicyType = VpnRoutingPolicyType.ForceAllTrafficOverVpn,
                UserAuthenticationMethod = VpnAuthenticationMethod.Eap,
                TunnelAuthenticationMethod = VpnAuthenticationMethod.Eap,
            };

            connectionProfile.Servers.Add("192.168.1.123");

            var credential = new PasswordCredential
            {
                UserName = "test",
                Password = "test123"
            };

            var status = await windowsVpnManager.AddProfileFromObjectAsync(connectionProfile);

            Debug.Print($"Connection status -> {status}");
        }
```

But this code always return status "other", if i create vpn profile from setting with a same properties, it work.

Comment: Where do you use `credential`?

Comment: On the next step i call  var await windowsVpnManager.ConnectProfileWithPasswordCredentialAsync(connectionProfile, credential);

Comment: Which exact Windows version?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro version 22H2 build 19045.2364

Comment: Could you please check if you have declared the `networkingVpnProvider` restricted capability first? And I'm confused about this: `if i create vpn profile from setting with a same properties, it work.` Do you mean it works when create different kind of VPN profile?

Comment: Yes, i'm have this capability. `Do you mean it works when create different kind of VPN profile?`  - Yes, if create from windows settings

Comment: It seems that you are accessing the local. I'm not sure if this is related to the network isolation of UWP app. UWP are running in sandbox so it can't directly access the system resources. Could you please try to enable the local loopback for your UWP app first? This action will allow UWP apps to access the local host. [Enabling loopback for a UWP application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/loopback#enabling-loopback-for-a-uwp-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peter Smith has already answered this issue on Microsoft Q&A here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1155880/uwp-vpn-addprofilefromobjectasync-always-return-ot

I will post a summary about the solution here as well.

**Answer from Perter:**

Please add the EapConfiguration node for your profile.  More information is listed here: [VPNv2CSP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/vpnv2-csp).

In the description of **VPNv2**/ProfileName/NativeProfile/Authentication/Eap it mentions that the Eap node is required; the only actual required item is the Eap/Configuration. There are steps for making a sample Eap configuration at [EAP Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/eap-configuration).

The code should be something like this:

```
connectionProfile.EapConfiguration = "<EapHostConfig xmlns=........ (long string removed)";
```